# Using Service for long network connection

Tags: android, android-service, android-networking

Right now I have a server running on a desktop.  I want to be able to start up my app, hit a button to start collecting data from this server, and only stop once I hit to button again.  The user should always be grabbing data from this server after hitting the button, even if the app isn't active.  So far I've considered setting up a Service or using Threads by themself.

A Service sounds exactly like what I need, but I've been told it isn't meant to sustain a long network connection.  I poked through the BluetoothChat sample application and it didn't use a Service.  Would a Service be the right thing to use then, or should I implement it with threads like the sample application does?  The only reason I need a long connection is to listen for any error reports from the server.  The other network stuff only happens when the user is directly using the app.  I will have to use threads anyways because a Service runs in the same thread as the activity that calls it, but I guess my main question is whether I should scrap the Service part.  Right now I have a basic Service set up that can handle messages sent to it and it seems really easy to use.  The documentation on it is just all over the place, there needs to be a section saying "If you want to do X, then this is suggested!"

Answer (score 1):

A Service runs on the UI thread, but an IntentService runs in its own thread.

It's ambiguous to say that the "app" isn't active. If you're running a Service, it's always active. An IntentService is active as long as it has finished the work in its onHandleIntent() method. None of the activities of the app may be active, which means that the app is in the background.

Other than that, I'd need to know more about what you're trying to do. In general, it's better to collect data in cycles rather than trying to keep the connection open constantly. For example, what do you do when the device loses connection to the Internet?

Comment: I will be streaming data that will be collected on the computer.  When the device loses connection to the internet then the streaming will momentarily stop until a connection is brought back up.  I will look into IntentService to see if it is what I need.